# Java string split by multiple character delimiter

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a project in Java, which collects data from a Linux machine and gets output like this:

> SwapCached:            0 kB

I need to split this sentence into this words:

> SwapCached,0

I know how to split by single characters, but don't know how to split with multiple words(like kB) and multiple spaces together.

**EDIT:** I tried this one but it didn't clear the spaces.

```
bolunmus[i]=line.split(":|\\ +|\\ |kB");
```

Comment: Hint: `split` takes a regex.

Comment: I edited my question. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: `String.replace()` followed by `.split()`?

Comment: Hint #2 - http://txt2re.com/ generates Java code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't clear spaces, because you didn't tell it to:

```
bolunmus[i]=line.split(" *(:|kB) *");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
line.split(":\\s+|\\skB");
```